# AngularJS testing a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I'm trying to test a simple service but I'm getting an `Unkown Provider` error.  Here is the service definition:

```
var sessionManager = angular.module('MyApp.SessionManager', ['ngResource']);
sessionManager.factory('UserService', function($resource) {
    var UserService = $resource('/api/users/:key', {}, {
        getNewUUID: {
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                action: 'getNewUserUUID'
            }
        }
    });

    return UserService;
});
```

and here is the test:

```
describe('Testing SessionManager', function() {

    var userService;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('MyApp.SessionManager');

        inject(function($injector) {
            userService = $injector.get('UserService');
        });
    });

    it('should contain a UserService', function() {
        expect(userService).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

I can't seem to see the problem, I know that the `UserService` javascript file is being called because I can get a console log at the top of the file, however if I put it in the service definition I don't see it get called.  So for some reason it's like Angular is not instantiating my service?

Comment: In your test runner, are you sure angular-resource.js is loaded?  That is where ngResource is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the problem was my module `MyApp.SessionManager` was being replaced because I thought you could declare dependencies every time it was reopened to add a module.  The code above is fine if of course the service is actually surviving up until the tests.